# database design - Should I have many column about uploaded image column or I should put it in new table with many rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

Hello I have a problem with insert and editing uploading multiple files. I have 3 images upload files.
if I insert in the second or third upload file, it will always result in first. (but if I upload all 3 images, it will work fine)

Now My database table is about photographer's event. Column look like this
event_id, model_name, max_photographer_qty, reserve_photographer_qty,.......
 and I have column name "location_img1" "location_img2" "location_img3"  in this table.

The question is Should I move this to new table and in new table has only id and one image column? I mean if upload 3 images then it will insert 3 rows in new table.  (my old table is insert 1 row with 3 column)

here is my code

```
$count=count($_FILES["images"]["name"]);

                $arr_newname = array();

            for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++)
            {   
              if ((($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1] == "image/gif")
             || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1]  == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1]  == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i-1] < 9000000)) //9 MB
            {

             if ($_FILES["images"]["error"][$i-1]  > 0)
             {
             echo "File Error : " . $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  . "<br />";
              }
              else 
             {
             // echo "Upload File Name: " . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]  . "<br />";
            // echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  . "<br />";
              //echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i]  / 1024) . " Kb<br />"; 

               if (file_exists("images/location/".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i-1] ))
              {
               echo "<b>".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i-1]  . " already exists. </b>";
               }
               else
              {
                $newname = "id".$id."_".date('Y-m-d')."_".$i.".jpg";  //ใช้$id จากparameter methodเลย
                array_push($arr_newname, $newname);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i-1] , "images/location/".$newname);
              //  echo "Stored in: " . "images/location/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ."<br />";
               ?>

              <?php
              }
             }
              }else
             {
              //echo "Invalid file detail ::<br> file type ::".$_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1] ." ,    file    size::: ".$_FILES["images"]["size"][$i-1] ;
              } 
            }




$data = array(
            'location_pic' => $arr_newname['0'],
            'location_pic2' => $arr_newname['1'],
            'location_pic3' => $arr_newname['2']
        );
        $this->db->where('event_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('oav_event', $data);
```

dgd

```
     <tr>
  <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Location pic1</label></td>
   <td width="30"></td>
   <td><input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Location pic2</label></td>
     <td width="30"></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Location pic3</label></td>
      <td width="30"></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" /></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: One image per row, in a new table.

Comment: You should show your database table and sample data instead of your PHP and HTML code

Comment: What if one day you need to add more images? You'll have to change the number of columns in your database. A program should be made with a mind of "I don't need to ever change that". Create a new table and add one image per row. You can create a column to number them, and you'll need to link them to the `oav_event` table.

Comment: Do _not_ splay an array of things across columns.  This is a very common question; the answer is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we all strongly recommend moving the images to a new table for scalability, however, I will let you know what is wrong with your code.

You are storing the names in `$arr_newname`, and for that you are using `array_push($arr_newname, $newname);` [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) will add numeric index automatically, meaning if you only upload the 3rd image, when you push the name to `$arr_newname`, it will become the first element of that array, with key = 0.

You should keep the relation between the index of `$_FILES["images"]["name"]` and `$arr_newname`, so you array_push should be replaced by this:

```
$arr_newname[$i-1] = $newname;
```